# Typescript:How to get type of class member generically

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
class Awesome<ObjType extends Object,
     KeyType extends keyof ObjType , 
     MemberType /* is of type obj:ObjType obj[KeyType]*/>{}
```

How to constrain `MemberType` here as type of member of instance of `ObjType`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your'e looking for `MemberType extends ObjType[KeyType]`.

> ... typing constructs that enable static validation of code involving dynamic property names and properties selected by such dynamic names ...
>
> — from the [Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11929) that implemented the feature

For your code, it works like this:

```
class Awesome<ObjType extends Object,
     KeyType extends keyof ObjType , 
     MemberType extends ObjType[KeyType]> { }

interface A { 
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

// okay:
type A1 = Awesome<A, keyof A, string | number>

// not okay:
type A2 = Awesome<A, keyof A, boolean>

// okay:
type A3 = Awesome<A, 'a', number>
type A4 = Awesome<A, 'b', string>

// not okay:
type A5 = Awesome<A, 'a', boolean>
type A6 = Awesome<A, 'b', Date>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

---

#### EDIT

As [Daniel Rosenwasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386952/daniel-rosenwasser) pointed out, `keyof` is called a "key query" and `ObjType[KeyType]` is an "indexed access type".

Comment: Actually the proper terms are "key queries (i.e. `keyof`) and "indexed access types" (a.k.a. "lookup types", i.e. `ObjType[KeyType]`).

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser Thanks! Updated :-)

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution to get class member's type in typescript `type MEMBER_OF<TObject extends Object, TKey extends keyof TObject> = TObject[TKey}`